# Replicate server to another enviroment

Tags: linux, replication

I am adopting a new enviroment for my application in production. My old env has a lot of configuration, like e-mail server, application server, database, java plataform, etc. I would like to replicate this enviroment and copy it to the new enviroment.

On the new env, I am able to select the linux distro, so I can use the same linux version.

Does anybody already had done this? What is the safer way of accomplishing the task?

Comment: Just restore your backups to the new server.  Keep the new server on an isolated network until you change network settings and make sure everything works properly.

Comment: @Grant, do you know a good application for creating/restoring the backup? And do you think that the difference of IP address or another network/hardware feature may cause a failure on some service, like email server or ftp?

Comment: If you don't already have backups, you've got bigger issues.  I'd recommend fixing that problem first, before touching anything else.  And yes, changing IP addresses will cause problems for many network services.  In most cases they just need their configuration files changed to the new IP or hostname.

Comment: The enviroment already has the backups, but they are kept by the provider, and I believe that I'll have to pay for it. So, probably I'll have to create my own copy of the enviroment. Do you know a software for creating full backups on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is probably to set up the new server, install the relevant packages / software(so that everything is properly installed for that distro/hardware)and then rsync the config files to the new server and make any system specific changes that may be needed.